# min-width and max-width are ignored when element has display:table-cell

Tags: css, css-tables

I'm trying to do simple fluid layout using [CSS tables technique](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/everything_you_know_about_CSS_Is_wrong/), but there is one big flaw that I have found in it: min-width and max-width are ignored on elements with table-cell display.

Do you know any workaround that would allow me to specify how far #sidebar element can stretch in the following example?

XHTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="main">
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
display: table-row;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

  #main {
  display: table-cell;
  }

  #sidebar {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 100px;  /* does not work! */
  max-width: 310px;  /* does not work! */
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Add another wrapper inside each div:

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="main">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And put the `*-width` declarations on them:

```
#sidebar div.inner {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding additional inner div allowed me to specify min-width. But adding max-width to inner div will not prevent #sidebar from growing bigger, here is screenshot: http://wstaw.org/d/5ed3

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at responsive design for a site that displays left -> right then down and want to achieve a min-width myself. Doing a bit of research I think this might answer this question.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/max-width/

Answer (score -1):

If you are just trying to do a sidebar and main setup, use float: left instead of table-row and table-cell. Then you can put your min-width on the id.

Comment: If you need the `aside` to be the same height as the `main` (or the other way around) floating them into each other isn't going to work. That's the reason for doing the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` thing in the first place.